# Where can I find a good discussion about scalar QED?

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, education

Currently, I'm working with scalar QED, but I didn't find a book treating the symmetries of the lagrangian, the transversal projector and other important topics. Which book or article is a good option to study the whole structure of the theory?

Comment: Chapter 9 of "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model" by M. D. Schwartz  is about scalar QED.

Comment: Itzykson & Zuber.